# Unable to pull or push using VS2017 in github

Tags: github

I am pushing changes to github repository. I am getting below error

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is discussed in detail in [this thread](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/949)

It appears that updating Visual Studio to version 2017 15.5.7 or later will fix this issue.